# my screen is stuck while starting?

Tags: boot, sudo, screen, startup, reboot

I've tried to update some packages and when I tried to reboot, after loading it's stuck in this screen. 
I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS
[image: I'm stuck in this screen]

Comment: I've tried recovery mode also but nothing happening also tried fsck but nothing seems to work

Comment: I saw Something that said try to installing ubuntu desktop and unity then try startx and I've tried it but the condition is same